# How to Overcome Undefined Variable Dicodeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

*I want to put the photos in the uploads folder but when I try to call the variable from the controller to the view it generates an Undefined Variable error*

***File : application/controllers/ubah_profile.php***

```
    public function ubah_profile()
    {
        $data['foto'] = $this->db->get_where('user',array('id'=>$this->session->userdata('id')),1)->row()->foto;
        $this->load->view('top',$data);
        $this->load->view('upload_foto');
        $this->load->view('bottom');
    }
```

***File : application/views/top.php***

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>uploads/<?php echo $foto; ?>" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
              <span class="hidden-xs">Admin</span>
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: You have to first define `$data = array()` in the controller.

Comment: what are you trying to get from this code? `$this->db->get_where('user',array('id'=>$this->session->userdata('id')),1)->row()->foto;`

how is your table user structure?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the form type my friend.
That’s why the controller can’t recieve the file info.
Btw, judulnya ada campuran bhs indo wkwk.